# GLSL - left and right shift operation issue

Tags: glsl

I am trying to use `<<`and `>>` operations within my GLSL shader (to unpack int from byte texture). However, if I use them, shader stop working and compiler write no error. Other operators like `|`, `&` works.

Answer (score 3):

`>` and `<` are operators that perform comparisons. The bit shifting operators are `>>` and `<<`.

Although these operators are recognized in GLSL, they were "reserved for future use" in version 1.20. They are legal in version 4.10, according to the specification. I don't know in which version they were introduced though.